# How to dynamicly show selected value from database with dropdown using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, dropdown, selected

I try to get value from table with dropdown, but it still static. How to make it dynamic?

a. table list
[image]

b. Controller.php

```
public function getValues($id) {
       $coba = Program::select('id_program','nama')->get();
       $cobaja = Program::find(1);
       return view('payment.index', compact('coba','cobaja'));
    }
```

c. index.php

```
<select id="filter-layanan" class="form-control"  input-sm>
                <option>Select Item</option>
                @foreach ($coba as $ca)
                <option value="{{ $ca->id_program }}" {{$cobaja->id_program == $ca->id_program  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $ca->nama}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

d. result

[image]

---

May someone help, please

Comment: What do you mean by make it dynamic?

Comment: @GzaiKun in the controller section, $cobaja = Program::find(1); || i try to make "1" to dynamic as anything what user select the menu, not just showing menu with "id = 1"

Comment: Your syntax appears correct. I would suggest you do some debugging on the value of `$cobaja->id_program` as that and `$coba->id_program` may never be equal.

Comment: @Peppermintology may u give the example, Sir? sorry, im still learning here.

Comment: Just do something simple like: `<option value="{{ $ca->id_program }}" {{$cobaja->id_program == $ca->id_program  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $ca->nama }} {{ $cobaja->id_program }} {{ $ca->id_program }}</option>` and compare all the values. Sorry, the comments suck for code (albeit you're not supposed to post code in comments anyway).

Comment: @Peppermintology how about the controller? because it stuck to get data with id=1

Comment: You don't have a column called `id` so `Program::find(1)` will not work as Laravel assumes a default `find` column is named `id`. You will need to tell Laravel which column is your [primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys).

Comment: @Peppermintology i think it set already as i use **route::resource** in the **web.php** and laravel do detect  **($id) = id_program** as well. Because, when i set the **Program::find(1)** , the default dropdown menu is **payment**. when i set **Program::find(5)**, the default dropdown menu is **pelanggan** || do i miss something ?

Comment: Did you do as I previously suggested and output the values in the option element?

Comment: @Peppermintology i did, but look like i was wrong. the output were like **payment 1 1** , **payment 1 5**
sorry because i dont really understand. this is the part of individual end-semester project for my college and my teacher really on busy giving guidence for all clasess

Comment: I’m confused now. Are you saying it is working? What’s the issue now?

Comment: @Peppermintology the dropdown result is success to show like **d.point** above. the issue is it cannot change the page even we choose another menu. Example : we open **payment.index** page, then we try to change to **pelanggan.index** page with the dropdown menu, it do nothing

Comment: You need to save the change in the database. You can’t just select a new option then go to another page and expect the value to be the same.

Comment: @Peppermintology oo, i understand that. do u have any reference, Sir?

Comment: Reference for what, how to save form data to your database?